# jquery toggle for show/hide div ...how to prevent page from jumping to the top?

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I have the following jquery script that shows/hides a div when someone clicks a link. The problem is that when someone clicks the link in the middle of the page, while the div does show and hide correctly, it also  makes the entire page jump to the top. How do I prevent this?

```
<a href="#" class="toggle-div">Show Div</a>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(".toggle").click(function(){
  $(".toggle-div").slideToggle("fast");
    $(this).html(function(i,html) {
        if (html.indexOf('Show') != -1 ){
           html = html.replace('Show','Hide');
        } else {
           html = html.replace('Hide','Show');
        }
        return html;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(".toggle").on('click', function (event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $(".toggle-div").slideToggle("fast");
    $(this).html(function(i,html) {
        if (html.indexOf('Show') != -1 ){
           html = html.replace('Show','Hide');
        } else {
           html = html.replace('Hide','Show');
        }
        return html;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: FANTASTIC!  Thank you.  I'm adding this to my toolbelt....